# Cisco ASA5505 compatible RAM

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I have a Cisco ASA5505 which I've acquired. It boots up first time successfully, and works without issue, however as soon as I reboot, it fails to boot with the flashing light sequence which indicates a RAM fault.

Fairly sure that replacing the RAM module will resolve the issue, however I'd rather not spend £120 on the official upgrade kit to replace the RAM, as it's only really something I'll be testing in a lab environment.

What alternate compatible RAM can I use in the device without spending a fortune? It's got a 256MB module at the moment.

Comment: OK, replacing the RAM in this instance didn't resolve the issue. Currently trying replacing both the RAM and the CF but not holding my breath...

Answer (score 0):

I'd [buy the RAM from eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?ssPageName=GSTL&_nkw=cisco%20asa%205505%20ram&_sop=2)... Either the official kit or find something listed as "compatible".